# Wordpress comment for virtual page

Tags: comments, url-rewriting

How to create separate comment section for all the virtual pages?

Is this even possible? Do I have to create separate table to store the comments and do all the work myself or is there any alternative for that?

If I have to create separate table, is there a way to use default wordpress functions in any way?

**EDIT:**

I haven't probably grasped the concept of custom post type yet or don't understand their power properly. Let me give you an example.

Say I have 2 database table. `wp_product_category` and `wp_product`. Each product will have a product_category. There are few products_category and thousands of products.

It's not possible to create all the pages manually. So, I have rewritten the URL and all the request is handled by a single page `product`. When someone goes to `product/product-category/` or `product/product-category/product-name`, the page is created comparing the values of `query_var` and making the content and title from the plugin.

I don't understand how custom post type can be used in this case. Any direction would be great help.

Comment: what's a *virtual* page?

Comment: @birgire A page that isn't an actual wordpress page/post. Rather it's generated by URL rewriting and other hooks.

Comment: What about embedding external comments to your *virtual* pages, like facebook or disqus ? Or try to create a hidden post (or some other custom post type) for each of your virtual pages, with `wp_insert_post()` so you can use the default WordPress commenting system

Comment: @birgire I don't understand what do you mean by embedding. These pages does not have any existence in the database. There will be thousands of pages divided into category and I am not sure how to assign each custom post type to each virtual page. If you can explain more, that will be a great help.

Comment: Is your data existing (as in database tables already in place, etc) or do you plan to organize it that way? In WordPress context it would make sense to create `product` as custom post type and `product_category` as custom taxonomy for it.

Comment: @Rarst The data is already in place and organized that way. But how those pages will be generated automatically from those database values. Does custom post type and taxonomy provide such option. I haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: Then sadly you are stuck that way (sans migrating it to CPT) and be ready to do a lot of wheel reinventing like your situation with comments.

Comment: @Rarst Okay, then I guess I have to do it the ugly way this time. But if I stumble into a similar situation in future, how can I do it with custom post type? Do I create a post with custom post type each time a product is added? If that's the case, can't I migrate all of the current `product` to a CPT and `product_category` to Custom Taxonomy?

Comment: @sakibmoon by embedding I meant that you can add some 3rd party javascript file and the external comments are fetched by the current page url (for example [Facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress comments are segmented by IDs of their parent posts.

For virtual pages you would either have to:

- replicate the process (by creating underlying Custom Post Type for it)
- or completely rebuild how it's handled for them (for example by tracking segments as comment meta and query accordingly)

Comment: There will be thousands of virtual pages under different category. I am not sure, how custom post type can handle that situation. If you can give me any example, that would be better.

Comment: Comment meta seems to be a nice suggestion. I understand how to do that. Can you suggest which hooks will be better to handle the situation? And if you think custom post type will be better to do this, please explain a little more about it. Thanks a lot. You have opened a new door for me.

Comment: @sakibmoon either way would be rather involved, comments are old concept and hadn't been made as much more generic as custom post types and taxonomies. If you have thousands of those pages I would questions why isn't custom post type used for them in first place.

Comment: Please see my edit. Sorry for the long edit. But I hope it will help you to give me a better direction.